# Add ">" symbol at front of each textarea line using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i don't know how to add this symbol '*' at front of every line of textarea. I have a hidden textarea which is `#repmsg`, and assume that in that box have 3 line. I want when user click `#modquote`, the confirm box will appear, and when user click OK, inside the `textarea#modrepmsg` will display

```
>line1
>line2
>line3
```

Here my jquery code

```
    $( '#modquote')
  .click(function() {
    if (confirm('ausdhkajsdhskj?'))
    {
        var comment = $('#repmsg').val();
        var regex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
        var repmsg = comment.replace(regex, "")
        var quote = '>' + repmsg;
        $('textarea#modrepmsg').val(quote);
    }
   });
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: ur split should be on \r or \n not <br>

Comment: also if you use regex for html you are gonna have a bad time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$('#modrepmsg').val(function() {
    return $('#repmsg').val().split('\n').map(function(line) {
        return '>'+line;
    }).join('\n');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cm7d6/

Answer (score 0):

you could replace \r\n or what ever return / linebreak is in the text area and replace with \r>

then preceed the content with >

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a regex that gets the beginning or a text line so ^ should be used

```
$( '#modquote')
.click(function() {
if (confirm('ausdhkajsdhskj?'))
{
    var comment = $('#repmsg').val();
    var repmsg = comment.replace("/^/g", ">")
    $('textarea#modrepmsg').val(repmsg );
}
});
```